# java: applying values to a column, 3d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

okay i was told to do a 3d array of ints named x blah blah, with 3 rows and 2 columns with 4 ints in each column. The elements in the first row are all 5, in the second row are all 7, and in the third row the first column is all 8 and the second column is 30, 31, 32, and 33.

```
int[][][] x = new int[3][2][]= {{5,5,5,5},{7,7,7,7},{8,30,31,32,33}};
```

this is what i came up with but im not sure about applying values to a "column"

yeah this is homework but im confused on what to do futher, this was the exact questions

Declare, create, and initialize a three-dimensional array of ints, x, that has 3 rows, each of which has 2 columns where each column is an array 4 ints. The elements in the first row are all 5, in the second row are all 7, and in the third row the first column is all 8 and the second column is 30, 31, 32, and 33.

Comment: Please post your exact assignment requirements. Something doesn't seem quite right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your array will hold 24 items: 3 * 2 * 4. The first row will hold 8 ints since it has 2 columns each holding 4 ints. Best to try to visualize this in your head but not as a flat row x column array, but in 3 dimensions with numbers sticking out of the page.

Also you'll need to nest curly braces 3 deep for this to be a 3-D array. Your attempt currently only nests parenthesis two deep as would be seen in a 2-D array. Since this is homework, we shouldn't solve this for you, but we can help you. So please try again and show us what you come up with.

**Edit**
Also, your code will not compile, so best to scrap it and try afresh. Again, if you hit a wall, please edit your post and notify us by comment of your changes.

Comment: int[][][] x = new int[][][]= 
x[0][1]= {5,5,5,5}
x[0][2]= {5,5,5,5}
x[1][0]= {7,7,7,7}
x[1][1]= {7,7,7,7}
x[2][0] ={8,8,8,8}
x[2][1] ={30,31,32,33}

so its kinda something like this.. the array layout i mean

Comment: @max: I'm not sure what you mean, but that's not the syntax for initializing arrays on declaration. Please add any code updates as an edit to your answer. Only non-code comments should go here.

Answer (score 0):

I pass for the same problem and i found that this works...

```
`int[][][] x = {{{5,5,5,5},{5,5,5,5}},
           {{7,7,7,7},{7,7,7,7}},
           {{8,8,8,8},{30,31,32,33}}};`
```

I already tested in eclipse.